# Difference between pi-pi* transition and intramolecular charge transfer ICT in organic solar cells?

Tags: computational-chemistry, charge-transfer

Intramolecular charge transfer (ICT( occurs from donors to acceptors in molecules. This phenomenon can be observed by visualizing the charge distribution patterns of HOMO and LUMO. While studying D-A systems , I came across two cases:

1. The HOMO and LUMO are spreading all over the pi skeleton from donor to acceptors.
2. The HOMO resides only on the donor fragment, whereas the LUMO is  localized on the acceptor component.

For case 1, does it means that $\pi$-$\pi^*$ transition is accompanied with ICT? For case 2, does it means that HOMO-->LUMO transition is of ICT type only?
Which of the cases displays the best ICT? Some books or benchmarks would be helpful.